# RANK() - Multiple columns in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been struggling with a query where i have to create one rank dimension for several different columns into one query.

I've tried to add multiple times the `RANK() OVER` clause, but it seems not to work with greater than 1 clause on the query.

Example:

```
John - Sales program A: 10000 - Sales program B: 123 - Sales program C: 585
Maria - Sales program A: 500 - Sales program B: 123213 - Sales program C: 432
```

I would need 3 columns with the rank of each Sales program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have several rank() operators, for any columns you like. The question / example data is quite vague, but you can do it just like this:

```
select
  person,
  A,
  rank() over (order by A) as A_RANK,
  B,
  rank() over (order by B) as B_RANK,
  C,
  rank() over (order by C) as C_RANK
from
  sales
```

If you data is different, for example the A, B and C are in different rows instead of columns, you can do for example a CTE that uses PIVOT to turn rows into columns.

Here's also your example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/997fd9/2).